CrewAI error when trying to use the LangChain tool: Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of BaseTool
Here is my code:
import os
from crewai import Agent, Task, Crew, Process
from crewai_tools import SerperDevTool
from langchain_community.tools import DuckDuckGoSearchResults
from langchain.agents import Tool
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'I deleted it'
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = 'deleted'
os.environ["OPENAI_MODEL_NAME"] ='gpt-4o'  # 根据可用模型进行调整



duckduckgo_search = DuckDuckGoSearchResults()

# 定义您的代理及其角色和目标
researcher = Agent(
  role='高级研究分析师',
  goal='揭示AI和数据科学的前沿发展',
  backstory="""您在一家领先的科技智库工作。
  您的专长在于识别新兴趋势。
  您擅长剖析复杂数据并提供可行的见解。""",
  verbose=True,
  allow_delegation=False,
  tools=[duckduckgo_search]
)
writer = Agent(
  role='技术内容策略师',
  goal='撰写引人入胜的科技进展内容',
  backstory="""您是一位著名的内容策略师，以深刻且引人入胜的文章而闻名。
  您将复杂概念转化为引人注目的叙述。""",
  verbose=True,
  allow_delegation=True
)

# 为您的代理创建任务
task1 = Task(
  description="""对2024年AI的最新进展进行全面分析。
  确定关键趋势、突破性技术和潜在行业影响。""",
  expected_output="完整的分析报告，以要点形式呈现",
  agent=researcher
)

task2 = Task(
  description="""根据提供的见解，撰写一篇引人入胜的博客
  文章，突出最重要的AI进展。
  您的文章应信息丰富且易于理解，适合科技爱好者。
  让它听起来酷一些，避免复杂的词汇，以免听起来像AI写的。""",
  expected_output="至少4段的完整博客文章",
  agent=writer
)

 # 使用顺序过程实例化您的团队
 crew = Crew(
  agents=[researcher, writer],
  tasks=[task1, task2],
  verbose=True, # 您可以将其设置为1或2以选择不同的日志级别
  process = Process.sequential
)

# 让您的团队开始工作！
result = crew.kickoff()

print("######################")
print(result)

The runtime error is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anacoda\envs\for_paper\src\cai.py", line 43, in <module>
    researcher = Agent(
                 ^^^^^^
  File "D:\anacoda\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 212, in __init__
    validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Agent
tools.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of BaseTool [type=model_type, input_value=Tool(name='duckduckgo_sea...'api', source='text'))>), input_type=Tool]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/model_type


You need to set up the DuckDuckGoSearchResults tool as a custom tool. See the official CrewAI documentation:

Subclassing BaseTool
To create a personalized tool, inherit from BaseTool and define the
necessary attributes, including the args_schema for input
validation, and the _run method.
from typing import Type
from crewai.tools import BaseTool
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyToolInput(BaseModel):
    """Input schema for MyCustomTool."""
    argument: str = Field(..., description="Description of the argument.")

class MyCustomTool(BaseTool):
    name: str = "Name of my tool"
    description: str = "What this tool does. It's vital for effective utilization."
    args_schema: Type[BaseModel] = MyToolInput

    def _run(self, argument: str) -> str:
        # Your tool's logic here
        return "Tool's result"


In your case, the following code should work:
from typing import Type
from crewai.tools import BaseTool
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from langchain_community.tools import DuckDuckGoSearchResults

class MyCustomDuckDuckGoToolInput(BaseModel):
    """Input schema for MyCustomDuckDuckGoTool."""
    query: str = Field(..., description="URL to search for.")

class MyCustomDuckDuckGoTool(BaseTool):
    name: str = "DuckDuckGo Search Tool"
    description: str = "Search the web for a given query."
    args_schema: Type[BaseModel] = MyCustomDuckDuckGoToolInput

    def _run(self, query: str) -> str:
        duckduckgo_tool = DuckDuckGoSearchResults()
        response = duckduckgo_tool.invoke(query)
        return response

